# Reason for skates sputtering along ice instead of stopping?

Tags: ice-hockey, ice-skating

I recently got my skates sharpened at SportChek and a couple days later I played hockey however whenever i tried to stop my skates would sputter along the ice and wouldnt dig in and spray up snow. I basically had to go back to when i was first learning to skate when i was 5 and stop by pointing my toes together.

This is not a case of me not being able to stop because I have played hockey for 13+ years and am a proficient skater.

What could be the reason for this? I have a few speculations which are:

1) Sportchek somehow screwed up the sharpening

2) Skate blade is too thick (Maybe sportchek took off the profiling with the last sharpen)

3) I was skating on an outdoor rink so maybe the ice was bad.

If anyone thinks any of these could be the cause or you have any input id love to hear it.

Comment: Number 2 sounds most valid to me, but don't underestimate the change in surface.  I'm not exactly OCD, but I try to avoid changing more than one thing at a time.  If I change surface, I don't change anything on my skates, not even the laces.  If I change something on my skates then I skate on the surface I skate on most.

Comment: @Val Ya thats a smart thing to do thanks. I skate at my usual rink tonight (indoor) so im going to just try and see how it works. If I get the same problem im going to go to a skate shop and get them profiled the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Just at theory, but it may be that they were sharpened with a [radius](http://www.wissota.com/learning-about-radius) other than you are used to...likely a smaller radius (and therefore deeper 'dish'). The smaller the radius, the more 'bite' the blade has.

Granted, that should affect both skates, but perhaps you're not noticing it on your stronger side.